# Question involving an infinite sheet of uniform charge with a hole and gauss theorem

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

When we put a circular hole of radius R on an infinite sheet of uniformly disturbed charge we do have an electrical field on a distance z (perpendicular to the sheet) from the center of the circular hole. But if we were to pick a gaussian surface such as a cylinder of radius R there would be no flux according to the gauss theorem. Because there would be no charge in the hole. I am having a difficult time understanding what i did wrong.

Comment: The integral over the flux would be zero, that does not say there is no E inside just the sum of all E going inside and outside is 0.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing wrong, it's just that no flux doesn't mean there is no electric field, it just means that there are as much field lines going into the surface as there are going out. In this case, you'll just have a hard time figuring out the field at that point using Gauss's law.

Comment: I understand that there would be as much field lines going in as there going out but i don't understand which lines produced by which part could go in?

Comment: @cevdetmyers  The ones produced by the part of the plane that wasn't cut out

Comment: But isnt all of the plane produces lines that goes outwards from the plane? How could the lines go into the surface is there a way i could imagine that? When we calculate the field it appears to be perpendicular to the plane

Comment: @cevdetmyers  Just draw it. Or alternatively put a cup upside down on a flat table. If you imagine that the points in the table are charged, can you see that the field lines go into the walls of the cylinder?

Comment: @cevdetmyers The field is perpendicular to the plane at the point you're considering yes, because of symmetry, but outside of it, that is, at the other points that constitute the cylinder, it does not. See it for yourself; as an exercise, try to calculate $E$ by brute force, via integration of the distribution. Use a radius of $1$ centered at $0$ for simplicity